# How is the boolean statement evaluated in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

So i just found out [0] == true is false, and [0] === true is also false, 
so i assumed [0] should be evaluated to false. But when I am writing

```
if([0]) {
   console.log("hi");
}
```

prints "hi"
That happens because Boolean([0]) returns true. But i think it should have returned false.
What am I thinking wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

JS engine interpretation is that it is a non empty array. Hence, a truthy value in If condition.